# Not able to receive GCM notification in some of android devices in background

Tags: android

Actually my application works fine and able to receive GCM push notifications but there are some of devices which are not receiving GCM notification in GCMIntentService only when my app is in background. devices are huwai honor,xiaomi's some models. So bellow is my code, Let me know if anybody gone through this problem earlier. Can anyone please help me on this?

1. Android manifest file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.app.testapp"
   android:installLocation="preferExternal"
   android:versionCode="41"
   android:versionName="4.1.7" >

   <uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion="8"
   android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <uses-feature
       android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
       android:required="true" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

   <permission
   android:name="com.app.testapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
   android:protectionLevel="signature" />

   <uses-permission android:name="com.app.testapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />

   <supports-screens
   android:anyDensity="true"
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:resizeable="true"
   android:smallScreens="true"
   android:xlargeScreens="true" />

   <application
   android:name="com.app.testapp.MyApplication"
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/SampleTheme">

   <activity
       android:name="com.app.testapp.activity.SplashActivity"
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       android:theme="@style/ActivityTheme">    

      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>

   <!-- GCM -->
   <receiver
       android:name="com.app.testapp.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
       android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
     <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

           <category android:name="com.app.testapp" />
     </intent-filter>
   </receiver>

   <!-- Services -->
   <service android:name="com.app.testapp.GCMIntentService" />
   ```
2. receiver:

   ```
     public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends
     com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {
             return "com.app.testapp.GCMIntentService";
     }
     }
   ```
3. Service:

   ```
   package com.app.testapp;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import com.app.testapp.util.Constants;
   import com.app.testapp.util.Logger;
   import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

   public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

   private static String TAG = "GCM";

       public MyGCMIntentService() {
       super(Constants.SENDER_ID);
       }

       @Override
       protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {
       Logger.logger(TAG, "onError");

       }

       String message = null;

       @Override
       protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

           message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
           Logger.logger(TAG, "onMessage message=" + message);

       }

       @Override
       protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
           Logger.logger(TAG, "onRegistered");

       }

      @Override
      protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
            Logger.logger(TAG, "onUnregistered");
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: According to [Implementing GCM Client on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client), I think you can read at `For existing apps that extend a WakefulBroadcastReceiver, Google recommends migrating to GCMReceiver and GcmListenerService.` tips

Comment: I tried and change all the things as per latest and google recommendation. Its working for all devices except huwai honor. Not able to resolve,